# why filtering using sql expression is better compared to a function applied in DataSet in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm reading the spark ultimat guid book, and it is stated that :

> by specifying a function we are forcing spark to evaluate this function on every row in our dataSet...For simple filters it is always preferred to write sql expression

I don't see why sql expression will be better, since the expression will be also applied to every row of the dataSet!!
 can anyone give me more detail ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using a column expression, Spark's optimizer has a chance to optimize the query as it can look "into" the filter and probably move it to a better place in order to improve the execution time.

#### Example:

Image you had a dataset consisting of two columns `id` and `data` and your logic would first group the dataset by the `id` column and sum up the `data` values. After this grouping operation only the group with `id = 2` should be kept. In this case it would be faster to filter first and then to sum. By implementing the filter as column expression Spark can detect this optimization and apply the filter first:

```scala
val dfParquet = spark.read.parquet(<path to data>)
val groupedDf = dfParquet.groupBy("id").sum("data")
val groupedDfWithColumnFilter = groupedDf.filter("id = 2")
val groupedDfWithFilterFunction = groupedDf.filter(_.get(0).equals(2))
```

If we check the execution plan of `groupedDfWithColumnFilter` we get

```
== Physical Plan ==
HashAggregate(keys=[id#0L], functions=[sum(data#1L)])
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200)
   +- HashAggregate(keys=[id#0L], functions=[partial_sum(data#1L)])
      +- Project [id#0L, data#1L]
         +- Filter (isnotnull(id#0L) && (id#0L = 2))
            +- FileScan parquet [id#0L,data#1L] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:.../id], PartitionFilters: [], 
                 PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(id), EqualTo(id,2)], ReadSchema: struct
```

So the filter is applied first and even pushed down to the parquet file reader.

The execution plan of `groupedDfWithFilterFunction` however shows that Spark cannot do this optimization and applies the filter as the last step, thus losing an optimization:

```
== Physical Plan ==
Filter <function1>.apply
+- HashAggregate(keys=[id#0L], functions=[sum(data#1L)])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#0L, 200)
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[id#0L], functions=[partial_sum(data#1L)])
         +- FileScan parquet [id#0L,data#1L] Batched: false, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[file:.../id], PartitionFilters: [], 
              PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct
```

---

Another way to see the difference is to look at the Spark UI. For my test case I have created a parquet file with 10 mio rows in 100 partitions.
In the SQL tab one can see that due to the pushed down filters for the `groupedDfWithColumnFilter` Spark only loads about 200K rows of data from disk whereas for `groupedDfWithFilterFunction` Spark needs to load all 10 mio rows:

[image]